# generate excel with chart from .NET

Tags: c#, excel, export, charts

I have a WPF application and I need to generate an excel file that also contains charts? What is the best way of doing that? If possible, I want to avoid using the excel interop. 
Thx,
L

Comment: this has nothing to do with WPF, try to edit the title to make it capturing the correct competences.Anyway using excel interop is a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StatisticsSheetExample

Comment: thx, I also just found it! Seems the only one that also supports charts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found http://epplus.codeplex.com. Think I'm going to give it a try, it supports charts.

Answer (score 0):

OfficeWriter is another mature .NET library for Excel that supports adding charts:

http://www.officewriter.com