# How to work with .xls file in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, xls

In a C# console application I have a `PointF[]` array.  I need to draw those points in an .xls chart file, but I need guidance how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361403/generate-excel-with-chart-from-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573972/excel-charts-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Comment: http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

Comment: Microsoft has a whole slew of `interop` assemblies that can help you here.  First among them (for what you want) is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.11).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)

I've used it before to do something like you're describing.

I started off creating an .xls file in Excel that had the correct chart which read values from a specific range of cells and so on. Then using the SDK I added/changed the values of those cells and saved a new version of the file. So basically I used the file created in Excel as a template that I could change whenever without changing the code (as long as the values are written to the same range of cells).

You could also put the value cells in a separate worksheet so that the user does not see them when opening the file...